# Can I find the codeline causing the crash from this backtrace?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, visual-studio-2017, backtrace

I have a backtrace like this, And I have the source code for `xswiftbus`. Is there a way to find out to which codeline the "numbers" belong?

So could I figure out my callstack from that. 
Either in QtC or VS2017.

I personally cannot reproduce the crash leading to this backtrace, but maybe I can at least see which functions are involved.

```
Backtrace is:
0 00007FF8EE00BE1B E:\X-Plane 11\Resources\plugins\xswiftbus\64\win.xpl+000000000000BE1B ()
1 00007FF8EE028D1D E:\X-Plane 11\Resources\plugins\xswiftbus\64\win.xpl+0000000000028D1D ()
2 00007FF8EE00A64D E:\X-Plane 11\Resources\plugins\xswiftbus\64\win.xpl+000000000000A64D ()
3 00007FF8EE028B19 E:\X-Plane 11\Resources\plugins\xswiftbus\64\win.xpl+0000000000028B19 ()
4 00007FF8EE00F025 E:\X-Plane 11\Resources\plugins\xswiftbus\64\win.xpl+000000000000F025 ()
5 00007FF9084E5202 E:\X-Plane 11\Resources\plugins\XPLM_64.dll+0000000000015202 ()
6 00007FF9084DB362 E:\X-Plane 11\Resources\plugins\XPLM_64.dll+000000000000B362 ()
7 00007FF7802156CA E:\X-Plane 11\X-Plane.exe+0000000000A456CA ()
8 00007FF77F8AA69E E:\X-Plane 11\X-Plane.exe+00000000000DA69E ()
```

Comment: An XPL file is basically a DLL. Do you have PDB or MAP files generated when you compile your code? If not, enable that. You can enable it for release build as well.

Comment: For my local build I have a `win.pdb` - for that release most likely not. My local build should be close to that crashed build, only I build a debug version while the above is a release version. Wonder if my file somehow would help.

Comment: Almost for sure problem is in code poinnted by frame `7` or below it. If this is release build you have to find symbols file for that build to locate actual line of your code. Then you analyze that piece of code

Comment: For XPlane (commercial software) I do NOT have symbols. My hope was that seeing the stack in my code at least gives a hint.

Comment: Do you have a dump file? If yes then just open it in VS2017. Then click frame `7`. It will complain that it can't find symbols file (provide it). Then it will complain it can't find source code then you have to provide location of that source code (remember to checkout code in proper version). Now VS should be able to show you date which will allow you to find the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no dump file has been generate, we have backtrace.io support in our application, but it did not write one

Comment: If you don't have the original debug symbols you can still just look at the function offsets of the public symbols and try to see the last function that came before it. That obviously can be very misleading. To get more accurate results you can open it in a reverse engineering tool like ghidra or IDA, if you have experience with either it's the easiest way I know to manually get some correlation between source and binary without dbgsymbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download and install [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools).
2. Get the XPL file that matches the release (if possible, e.g. download that version) and rename it to DLL.
3. Choose "Start debugging" and then "open dump file", even if you don't have a dump file.
4. Select the renamed DLL file
5. Type `.symopt +40` in order to allow symbols to be loaded that do not match the binary.
6. Type `.symfix` to get Microsoft symbols
7. Type `.sympath+ <path to your PDB>`
8. Type `ln <address>`

That should give an output like

```
0:000> ln 10009a9d
(10009a90)   MNbasic!str_encode_num_str+0xd   |  (10009b80)   MNbasic!str_alpha_num_code
```

So instead of just an offset, you now have a method name and an offset. If the offset is still very large, the symbols may be too far off.